# How to add pusher parameters into my laravel / filamentphp app?

Tags: laravel, pusher, laravel-filament

I want to add pusher parameters into my laravel 9 / filament": "^2.17.17 app and reading docs:
https://filamentphp.com/docs/2.x/admin/notifications#echo

I see some parameters used in config/filament.php file.
I am confused which parameters have I to use ?
In pusher console I see next :

```
app_id = "NNNN"
key = "KKKKKKKKK"
secret = "XXXXXXX"
cluster = "eu"
```

In .env file I have FROM INSTALL:

```
VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
VITE_PUSHER_HOST="${PUSHER_HOST}"
VITE_PUSHER_PORT="${PUSHER_PORT}"
VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME="${PUSHER_SCHEME}"
VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

So I remade my .env as :

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher

VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY="KKKKKKKKK"  # key parameter from pusher console
VITE_PUSHER_HOST="127.0.0.1" # not sure, looks like it must be ip from /etc/hosts of  my local apache 2 host ?
VITE_PUSHER_PORT="6001" # constant value?
VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME="http" # Now I am on my local apache 2 host
VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="eu"   # cluster parameter from pusher console
```

Not clear where in config to use :
app_id parameter from pusher console
secret parameter from pusher console

?

Answer (score 1):

Update your config/broadcasting.php See below example.

```
'connections' => [
        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'encrypted' => true,
                'useTLS' => true,
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: I have chaked config/broadcasting.php file - it has all options in your post. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: I dont understand.You asked where to use your pusher app id. From the config it shows add env variable PUSHER_APP_ID so add the id in the env